# Why does this code not download the file?

Tags: vba, loops, download

Here is the code, please help! I'm so lost. It successfully goes through each ID in the database.txt but every time it throws the exception and reports cannot download. I'm at my wits end, I've tried changing this so many times but nothing. The idea here is to download a file based on the date and the user id.

If its not found - catch the exception, if it is found - print in the datagridview.

Loop until all the IDs have been read.

```
Dim myDate = Format(DateTimePicker2.Value, "yyyyMMdd")

    Do Until DateTimePicker2.Value > DateTimePicker3.Value
        For Each strID As String In System.IO.File.ReadAllLines("database.txt")
            Try
                My.Computer.Network.DownloadFile("ftp://user:pass@ftp.ftp.net/" & strID & "/" & myDate & ".txt", My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath & "\logs\" & strID & "\" & Format(DateTimePicker2.Value, "yyyyMMdd") & ".txt")
            Catch nullDownload As System.Net.WebException
                MsgBox("File " & strID & "\" & Format(DateTimePicker2.Value, "yyyyMMdd") & ".txt could not be downloaded")
            End Try

            If My.Computer.FileSystem.FileExists(My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath & "\logs\" & strID & "\" & Format(DateTimePicker2.Value, "yyyyMMdd") & ".txt") Then
                For Each line As String In
            System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath & "\logs\" & strID & "\" & Format(DateTimePicker2.Value, "yyyyMMdd") & ".txt")
                    DataGridView1.Rows.Add(line.Split(","))
                Next
            End If
        Next

        DateTimePicker2.Value = DateTimePicker2.Value.AddDays(1)
    Loop


    If DateTimePicker2.Value > DateTimePicker3.Value Then
        MsgBox("Download complete.")
    End If
```

EDIT: Just wanted to clear some things up...this fails to download ANYTHING. Even if the file exists. I can pull the existing file using a separate function in my application so I know it works and I know the downloading code works. Something is just missing here...

Also for clarity the file address should be ftp://ftp.ftp.net/ID9999/20150718.txt

Comment: What exception?  What's the actual error and where does it happen?

Comment: if i remove the Try...Catch it throws a webexception when attempting to download the file and it doesn't exist.

Comment: Well, you can't download a file that doesn't exist.  It's not really clear what the issue is.

Comment: but the files that DO exist aren't being downloaded.

Comment: Then how do *those* ones fail?

Comment: they don't fail, it just simply doesn't download them. hence the name of the question :) ?

Comment: Well, I would consider not downloading to be a kind of failing in this case.  When you step through the code in a debugger, what happens?  Is the request made to download the file?  What is the server's response?  What does the code do with that response?

Comment: I'm not familiar with debugging other than staring at the screen until I come up with something else to try lol. This is my first real project. I am using Visual Studio 2012 if you can point me in the right direction.

Comment: oh and the server returns 550 file does not exist if i remove the Try..Catch and the file does not exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HUZZAH! It was the date. by using the date as a variable, it fails.

Instead of

```
My.Computer.Network.DownloadFile("ftp://user:pass@ftp.ftp.net/" & strID & "/" & myDate & ".txt", My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath & "\logs\" & strID & "\" & Format(DateTimePicker2.Value, "yyyyMMdd") & ".txt")
```

I use

```
My.Computer.Network.DownloadFile("ftp://user:pass@ftp.ftp.net/" & strID & "/" & Format(DateTimePicker2.Value, "yyyyMMdd") & ".txt", My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath & "\logs\" & strID & "\" & Format(DateTimePicker2.Value, "yyyyMMdd") & ".txt")
```